# how to set custom text interface on the top of image view?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-listview

I'm wanting to implement a custom text interface, with touch+drag selecting text and the keyboard not being raised, on the image view where user can type his own text and save it on the image view.can anyone help please?
here is my full image activity class

```
  public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

here is my xml file

```
  <FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fullimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="yourtext" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override ImageView and add a setText Method.

The text you set in that Method can be added to the View by adding it to the onDrawMethod of the View.

By catching the onTouchEvent on the CustomImageView you can move your text on the image. But you would have to have two activities. Activity a where you select the Image you want to show/edit and type the text, after you have done that, you can move to the next acitivity and show the text on the selected image.

http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/ - this should show you how to draw text to the Canvas
and this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html should get you started concerning touch events.

Need anything else?

Comment: can u help me with any tutorial?